# Is there a way to specify a super-type sub-type relationship in Oracle Designer?

Tags: oracle, database-design

I was wondering if it is possible to create a super-type sub-type relationship in Oracle Designer. I would like to create something like this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [temple.edu](http://ww2.cis.temple.edu/cis109friedman/CIS%20109%20-%20Lecture%20Set%20III%20-%20ERD%20and%20EERDs%20and%20Modeling/Emp-super.gif))</sub>

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In entity relationship diagrams subtypes are created by creating a new entity inside an existing entity like this example from [InformIT.com](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=101586&seqNum=7):

[image: ERD Diagram]
<sub>(source: [informit.com](http://www.informit.com/content/images/chap3_0130282286/elementLinks/03fig28.gif))</sub>

This shows that ORDER has subtypes PURCHASE ORDER and SALES ORDER, i.e. every ORDER is **either** a PURCHASE ORDER **or** a SALES ORDER.

Subtypes can be nested to any depth.

Although this example doesn't show any, subtypes can also have their own attributes and relationships.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I also found something called arcs. Do arcs perform the same function as what you mentioned above?

Comment: No, arcs represent alternative relationships - e.g. an ORDER LINE may be for purchase of a PRODUCT or for purchase of a SERVICE (but not both).

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you're working in the Design Editor on the physical model, you have to implement as actual tables.

But take a look at the documentation for the Foreign Key property "Arc", which might help some. You can set it so that exactly 1 of several foreign keys can have a value.

For example, you might set up FK's from your supertype table to each subtype table. Then enforce that exactly one can have a value by using that property and generating the TAPI for the tables. (The drawback is that you'd have to insert the subtype information before the supertype.)